# TypeScript | Immutable | proper way of extending Immutable.Map type

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I have a react-redux application written in typescript with immutable package. There I have a data, which comes from api and in store I pack it to Map. In all application they are used as a Map.

I created an interface:

```
export interface PaymentMethod extends Immutable.Map<string, string | NamedType<number>> {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    accountNr: string;
    paymentMethodType: NamedType<number>;
}
```

In general it works very good. Except tests, where I create data this way:

```
const dummyPaymentMethod: PaymentMethod = Map({
    id: '',
    name: '',
    description: '',
    accountNr: '',
    paymentMethodType: { id: 1, name: '' },
});
```

and then I get a lint error:

```
Error:(116, 13) TS2322:Type 'Map<string, string | { id: number; name: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'PaymentMethod'.
Property 'id' is missing in type 'Map<string, string | { id: number; name: string; }>'.
```

I feel totally lost, as I can see id in interface and in my dummy data.

I would appreciate some light on it. I feel that somehow I should pass the list of acceptable keys to my Map, but no idea, how to do this.

EDIT: misspell

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We used it like this in our project (slightly different approach):

```
interface ImmutableMap<T> extends Map<string, any> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
}
```

We used an older version of the `Immutable.js` typings that didn't used mapped types yet (`T[K]`). AFAIK typings are updated since then and there is no need to overwrite the `get` method.

*EDIT: Actually the `get` method still is not fully type safe unlike the above. So overwriting the method still has its merits.*

With the above declaration you can then create immutable maps like:

```
type AuthState = ImmutableMap<{
  user:string|null;
  loggedIn:boolean;
}>;

const authState:AuthState = fromJS({ user: 'Alice', loggedIn: true });
```

---

Ideally, you would like typings like this:

```
/**
 * Imaging these are typings for your favorite immutable
 * library. We used it to enhance typings of `immutable.js`
 * with the latest TypeScript features.
 */
declare function Immutable<T>(o: T): Immutable<T>;
interface Immutable<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
  set<S>(o: S): Immutable<T & S>;
}

const alice = Immutable({ name: 'Alice', age: 29 });
alice.get('name');      // Ok, returns a `string`
alice.get('age');       // Ok, returns a `number`
alice.get('lastName');  // Error: Argument of type '"lastName"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'.

const aliceSmith = alice.set({ lastName: 'Smith' });
aliceSmith.get('name');     // Ok, returns a `string`
aliceSmith.get('age');      // Ok, returns a `number`
aliceSmith.get('lastName'); // Ok, returns `string`
```

[Link to the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Imaging%20these%20are%20typings%20for%20your%20favorite%20immutable%0D%0A%20*%20library.%20We%20used%20it%20to%20enhance%20typings%20of%20%60immutable.js%60%0D%0A%20*%20with%20the%20latest%20TypeScript%20features.%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20Immutable%3CT%3E(o%3A%20T)%3A%20Immutable%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20Immutable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20get%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(name%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20set%3CS%3E(o%3A%20S)%3A%20Immutable%3CT%20%26%20S%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20alice%20%3D%20Immutable(%7B%20name%3A%20'Alice'%2C%20age%3A%2029%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aalice.get('name')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60string%60%0D%0Aalice.get('age')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60number%60%0D%0Aalice.get('lastName')%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22lastName%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22name%22%20%7C%20%22age%22'.%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20aliceSmith%20%3D%20alice.set(%7B%20lastName%3A%20'Smith'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0AaliceSmith.get('name')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60string%60%0D%0AaliceSmith.get('age')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20a%20%60number%60%0D%0AaliceSmith.get('lastName')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20returns%20%60string%60%0D%0A)

---

In order to achieve the above with `Immutable.js` you can create a small helper function, whose only purpose is to "fix" typings:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

interface Immutable<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
  set<S>(o: S): Immutable<T & S>;
}

function createImmutable<T extends object> (o:T) {
  return fromJS(o) as Immutable<T>;
}
```

Note that I used `fromJS` in the example. This will create a `Map` as long as the passed input is an `Object`. The benefit of using `fromJS` over `Map` is that the typings are easier to overwrite.

Side note: You might also want to look into `Record`s.

Comment: Thanks, I got very useful information from your answer.

Comment: Would this apply to `Record` (with just `get`) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving that here in case it helps someone:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

export interface ImmutableMap<JsObject extends object> extends Omit<Map<keyof JsObject, JsObject>, 'set' | 'get' | 'delete'> {
    set: <AKeyOfThatJsObject extends keyof JsObject>(key: AKeyOfThatJsObject, value: ValueOf<Pick<JsObject, AKeyOfThatJsObject>>) => ImmuMap<JsObject>;
    get: <AKeyOfThatJsObject extends keyof JsObject>(key: AKeyOfThatJsObject) => ValueOf<Pick<JsObject, AKeyOfThatJsObject>>;
    delete: <AKeyOfThatJsObject extends keyof JsObject>(key: AKeyOfThatJsObject, value: ValueOf<Pick<JsObject, AKeyOfThatJsObject>>) => ImmuMap<JsObject>;
}
```

It's really working great for us!

We use it like so: `const aMap: ImmutableMap<OneOfOurObjectTypes>`

**Example Usage:**

```
type BarType = { bar: string };

const foo: BarType = {
    bar: 'abc';
};
const immutableBar: Immutable<BarType> = Map(foo);
// immutableBar.get suggests bar as the key, and knows that the result is a string.
```

Comment: `ValueOf` is not defined. Same as `ImmuMap<JsObject>` but i expect it to be `ImmutableMap<JsObject>`. Maybe `ValueOf` is part of `type-fest` package? (`yarn add type-fest`)<

Answer (score 1):

If you find yorself using `immutable.js` maps more and more like native objects, it could be that a library like [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) is more suitable.

Otherwise, here's an example of a complete version, including `filter` etc:

```js
import { fromJS, Map } from 'immutable'
type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;
type AnyObject = Record<string, any>

export const TypedMap = <T extends AnyObject>(val: T) => 
fromJS(val) as any as TypedMap<T>

export type TypedMap<T extends AnyObject> = 
    Modify<Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>, TypedMapBase<T>>

export interface TypedMapBase<T extends AnyObject>  {
    set: <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => this
    get: <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => T[K]
    delete: <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => boolean
    deleteAll<K extends keyof T>(keys: Iterable<K>): this
    remove<K extends keyof T>(key: K): this
    removeAll<K extends keyof T>(keys: Iterable<K>): this
    update<K extends keyof T>(key: K, notSetValue: T[K], updater: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): this
    update<K extends keyof T>(key: K, updater: (value: T[K]) => T[K]): this
    merge<KC, VC, K extends keyof T>(
        ...collections: Array<Iterable<[KC, VC]>>
        ): Map<K | KC, T[K] | VC>
    merge<C, K extends keyof T>(
        ...collections: Array<{ [key: string]: C }>
    ): Map<K | string, T[K] | C>
    concat<KC, VC, K extends keyof T>(
        ...collections: Array<Iterable<[KC, VC]>>
    ): Map<K | KC, T[K] | VC>
    concat<C, K extends keyof T>(
        ...collections: Array<{ [key: string]: C }>
    ): Map<K | string, T[K] | C>
    mergeWith<K extends keyof T>(
        merger: <K extends keyof T>(oldVal: T[K], newVal: T[K], key: K) => T[K],
        ...collections: Array<Iterable<[K, T[K]]> | { [key: string]: T[K] }>
    ): this
    mergeDeep<K extends keyof T>(
        ...collections: Array<Iterable<[K, T[K]]> | { [key: string]: T[K] }>
    ): this
    mergeDeepWith<K extends keyof T>(
        merger: (oldVal: unknown, newVal: unknown, key: unknown) => unknown,
        ...collections: Array<Iterable<[K, T[K]]> | { [key: string]: T[K] }>
    ): this
    map<M, K extends keyof T>(
        mapper: (value: T[K], key: K, iter: this) => M,
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<K, M>
    mapKeys<M, K extends keyof T>(
        mapper: (key: K, value: T[K], iter: this) => M,
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<M, T[K]>
    mapEntries<KM, VM, K extends keyof T>(
        mapper: (
            entry: [K, T[K]],
            index: number,
            iter: this
        ) => [KM, VM],
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<KM, VM>
    flatMap<KM, VM, K extends keyof T>(
        mapper: (value: T[K], key: K, iter: this) => Iterable<[KM, VM]>,
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<KM, VM>
    filter<F extends T[K], K extends keyof T>(
        predicate: (value: T[K], key: K, iter: this) => value is F,
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<K, F>
    filter<K extends keyof T>(
        predicate: (value: T[K], key: K, iter: this) => unknown,
        context?: unknown
    ): this
    flip<K extends keyof T>(): Map<T[K], K>
}
```

And a partial extension:

```js
export const PartialTypedMap = <T extends AnyObject>(val: Partial<T>) => 
    fromJS(val) as any as PartialTypedMap<T>


export type PartialTypedMap<T extends AnyObject> = Modify<TypedMap<T>, PartialTypedMapBase<T>>

interface PartialTypedMapBase<T extends AnyObject>{
    get: <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => T[K] | undefined
    update<K extends keyof T>(key: K, updater: (value: T[K]|undefined) => T[K]): this
    mapEntries<KM, VM, K extends keyof T>(
        mapper: (
            entry: [K, T[K]],
            index: number,
            iter: this
        ) => [KM, VM] | undefined,
        context?: unknown
    ): Map<KM, VM>
}
```