# Immutability in React-Redux app - Immutablejs and Typescript Conflict

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, immutability, immutable.js

We have a problem with `Immutable.js` in combination with `TypeScript`, and your opinion is appreciated:

In the past year, we are working on a react-redux app.

As recommended in almost any best practice, common sense and in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html), our store data is immutable.

As recommended in the redux docs above, as used in many big projects, and as many boilerplates are implementing, we are using [`Immutable.js`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

We also write our app in [`TypeScript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

The problem is, that these two (`Immutable.js` and `TypeScript`) cannot play nice. Once using `toJS` or `get` or `getIn` to convert an immutable object to a normal JS object, the type is changed to `any`, and this breaks the type-safety between the store and the component.

### We tried

1. **Cast:**

`state.users.getIn(['counts', visits]) as number` but we hoped for a better type-safety.

2. **Fix `Immutable.js`'s typing:**

We also tried to type it ourselfs, and sometimes got as far as

```
interface ImmutableMap<T> {
 get<K extends keyof T>(name: K): T[K];
 set<S>(k: string, o: S): ImmutableMap<T & S>;
 getIn(searchKeyPath: any[], notSetValue?: any): T;
}
```

(idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607652/typescript-immutable-proper-way-of-extending-immutable-map-type))

*Assuming that `getIn` is only called with `toJS` and always return a JS object (which we do sometimes in our [higher-order-component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) - but that’s another story).*

But this is crap and a big hack.
We came to the conclusion that it is impossible to fix the type-safety of `Immutable.js` ourselves.*

3. **Vanilla:**

We tried to go vanilla, with object spread, but as the data structure became complicated, the merging of immutable objects became too complex and generated an unreadable code:

```
{
    ...state,
    profiles: {
      ...state.profiles,
      [id]: {
        ...state.profiles[id],
        meta: {
          ...state.profiles[id].meta,
          [sub]: payload,
        },
      },
    },
```

And we ended up building another `Immutable.js` library that we will need to maintain - too much code to support.

**about the record option**

We want to avoid using `record` - it produces a big pile of js code in the end browser, that is needed only for `TypeScript` and not necessary for the user, it is hell to maintain, and at the end does not share the full, same API as a pure JS object. I worked with it in past projects, and it was a very a bad experience.

### Questions

My questions are for people who created/working with complicated React-Redux apps:

1. Does anybody suffer from the same issue? Got a good solution to work with `Immutable.js` and `TypeScript`?
2. Anybody got a recommendation for a better library/solution, for good immutability and type-safety?

Comment: I agree on Immutable.js not working well with TypeScript. I personally use your option 3 ("vanilla"), but it does sometimes get a bit messy. I try not to nest my state too deeply though so in most cases it works well. A possible library you may try is [Immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) which I haven't used yet but it looks good for TypeScript in particular (definitions are included with the library).

Comment: Consider using immer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update:

Eventually, after some benchmarking and facebook-groups discussions, we converted to `immer` and we don't want to look back. great solution - typed, simple, objects are native so no need to learn a new api... We are happy.